# django get data using multiple objects by referring to foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have two data models, one is User and other one is ShibUser, ShibUser associate with User by storing User table's id as its Foreign Key.

Here is my ShibUser Table:

```
+----+--------------+------------------+----------------+
| id | auth_user_id | shib_username    | shib_user_role |
+----+--------------+------------------+----------------+
|  1 |            4 | auser@domain.edu | Student        |
|  2 |            5 | buser@domain.edu | Student        |
+----+--------------+------------------+----------------+
```

from django.db import models
from askbot.deps.django_authopenid.models import User

```
class ShibUser(models.Model):
    auth_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    shib_username = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    shib_user_role = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

Here is my User (auth_user) table:

```
+----+----------------+------------+--------+
| id | username       | reputation | status |
+----+----------------+------------+--------+
|  4 | aaUser         |          1 | w      |
|  5 | MrBUser_Cool   |          1 | w      |
+----+----------------+------------+--------+
```

Model Definition for User:

```
class User(models.Model):
    """
    Users within the Django authentication system are represented by this
    model.

    Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and '
                    '@/./+/-/_ characters'))
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('e-mail address'), blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(_('superuser status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates that this user has all permissions without '
                    'explicitly assigning them.'))
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('last login'), default=timezone.now)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True, help_text=_('The groups this user belongs to. A user will '
                                'get all permissions granted to each of '
                                'his/her group.'))
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission,
        verbose_name=_('user permissions'), blank=True,
        help_text='Specific permissions for this user.')
    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.username,)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%s/" % urllib.quote(smart_str(self.username))

    def is_anonymous(self):
        """
        Always returns False. This is a way of comparing User objects to
        anonymous users.
        """
        return False

    def is_authenticated(self):
        """
        Always return True. This is a way to tell if the user has been
        authenticated in templates.
        """
        return True

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = make_password(raw_password)

    def check_password(self, raw_password):
        """
        Returns a boolean of whether the raw_password was correct. Handles
        hashing formats behind the scenes.
        """
        def setter(raw_password):
            self.set_password(raw_password)
            self.save()
        return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)

    def set_unusable_password(self):
        # Sets a value that will never be a valid hash
        self.password = make_password(None)

    def has_usable_password(self):
        return is_password_usable(self.password)

    def get_group_permissions(self, obj=None):
        """
        Returns a list of permission strings that this user has through his/her
        groups. This method queries all available auth backends. If an object
        is passed in, only permissions matching this object are returned.
        """
        permissions = set()
        for backend in auth.get_backends():
            if hasattr(backend, "get_group_permissions"):
                if obj is not None:
                    permissions.update(backend.get_group_permissions(self,
                                                                     obj))
                else:
                    permissions.update(backend.get_group_permissions(self))
        return permissions

    def get_all_permissions(self, obj=None):
        return _user_get_all_permissions(self, obj)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        """
        Returns True if the user has the specified permission. This method
        queries all available auth backends, but returns immediately if any
        backend returns True. Thus, a user who has permission from a single
        auth backend is assumed to have permission in general. If an object is
        provided, permissions for this specific object are checked.
        """

        # Active superusers have all permissions.
        if self.is_active and self.is_superuser:
            return True

        # Otherwise we need to check the backends.
        return _user_has_perm(self, perm, obj)

    def has_perms(self, perm_list, obj=None):
        """
        Returns True if the user has each of the specified permissions. If
        object is passed, it checks if the user has all required perms for this
        object.
        """
        for perm in perm_list:
            if not self.has_perm(perm, obj):
                return False
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        """
        Returns True if the user has any permissions in the given app label.
        Uses pretty much the same logic as has_perm, above.
        """
        # Active superusers have all permissions.
        if self.is_active and self.is_superuser:
            return True

        return _user_has_module_perms(self, app_label)

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])

    def get_profile(self):
        """
        Returns site-specific profile for this user. Raises
        SiteProfileNotAvailable if this site does not allow profiles.
        """
        if not hasattr(self, '_profile_cache'):
            from django.conf import settings
            if not getattr(settings, 'AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE', False):
                raise SiteProfileNotAvailable(
                    'You need to set AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in your project '
                    'settings')
            try:
                app_label, model_name = settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE.split('.')
            except ValueError:
                raise SiteProfileNotAvailable(
                    'app_label and model_name should be separated by a dot in '
                    'the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE setting')
            try:
                model = models.get_model(app_label, model_name)
                if model is None:
                    raise SiteProfileNotAvailable(
                        'Unable to load the profile model, check '
                        'AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in your project settings')
                self._profile_cache = model._default_manager.using(
                                   self._state.db).get(user__id__exact=self.id)
                self._profile_cache.user = self
            except (ImportError, ImproperlyConfigured):
                raise SiteProfileNotAvailable
        return self._profile_cache
```

I have a form which represent the user profile and I want to show the role of the user, I have import both the objects in my form but I am struggling on how to really get the user role based on User objects username.

Here is the exact place I am trying to add this:

```
from askbot.shibapp.models import ShibUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        logging.debug('initializing the form')
        shib_user_role = ShibUser.objects.get(auth_user=4)
        if askbot_settings.EDITABLE_SCREEN_NAME:
            self.fields['username'] = UserNameField(label=_('Screen name'))
            self.fields['username'].initial = user.username
            self.fields['username'].user_instance = user
        self.fields['email'].initial = user.email
        self.fields['realname'].initial = user.real_name
        self.fields['website'].initial = user.website
        self.fields['city'].initial = user.location
        if askbot_settings.EDITABLE_SCREEN_NAME:
        self.fields['role'].initial = "test_role" (Instead of 'test_role')
```

I am very new to django world.

Comment: Please post your model definitions.

Comment: Shouldn't ShibUser -> User be a OneToOne relation?

Comment: yes it is one to one.

Comment: auth_user table is not something I implemented it comes with the framework that i use. I add the ShibUser table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I think you're trying to go from auth.User.username to ShibUser to do this follow the ForeignKeys backwards:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=username)
# for reverse relationships the foo_set is created by django enabling 
# reverse relationship.  You can override this by providing a related_name
shibuser = user.shibuser_set.get()
# Alternative syntax
shibuser = user.shibuser_set.all()[0]
```

From there you can get your ShibUser role.  If More than one ShibUser can exist per User then you want to drop the index and will instead have a queryset of ShibUser objects to work with.

If only one ShibUser object can exist per User you should make this a OneToOneField instead of a foreignkey and things become simpler:

```
shibuser = user.shibuser
```

Finally you can even start from the ShibUser model and work with it:

```
shibuser = ShibUser.objects.get(auth_user__username=username)
# Or if you already had the User object instance
shibuser = ShibUser.objects.get(auth_user=user)
```

Keep in mind several exceptions can be raised around this depending on the approach: the User could not exist or the ShibUser for the given User could not exist.  Perhaps more than one ShibUser could be related to a single user and therefore the .get() calls will result in a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception.  Your schema isn't very tight to your use case it sounds like so I would probably improve that with a OneToOneField

Comment: This did work, but in my form as you see I already have user object so instead of `user = User.objects.get(username=username)` can I use use that object?

Comment: I think you might be able to do the same with just `user.shib_user`. Or, try using [related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

Comment: @find-missing-semicolon for sure if you already have the User object you can use it.  I'm going to edit a third way to do this lookup as well